# Microfrontends - web components bundles

Tags: web-component, custom-element, micro-frontend

I'm researching about splitting our monolith into micro-frontends.
I think I found Web Components to be the best way for me but I would like to understand better. This is how my Web App looks like now:

1. Multiple web apps, which expose js file that exports a Web Component. On render, the web component will render for example Vue app / react etc...
2. Root index.html, which imports the web apps (`<script src="domain.com/micro-app1.js">`), and using them ("`<micro-app1>`").

My question is, with this method, all my micro-apps bundles are loaded (because of import using `<script src>`). Is there a lazy loading way?

Is there other better way?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `<script>` with `async` of `defer`, this will implement a kind of lazy loading.

You could also use a module loader like RequireJS (or your own) to import some custom elements only when needed.

Or place the  element in the preferred place in the HTML code flow to optimize the loading. For example at the bottom of the main page.

Comment: esmodules are asynchronous by nature and are therefore another option. They have some caveats though. Though they can also be used with defer, if one needs..

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by lazy loading? If you only want to load your apps, *when* they are *needed*, simply *lazy load* them :), i.e. do not load them in *advance* but have logic in place that adds a `<script>` tag *dynamically* when they are needed. The nice thing about Web Components is, that they support this use case natively:

```html
<!-- ... -->
<micro-app1 />
<micro-app2 />
```

`<micro-app2>` will automagically *upgraded* (i.e. rendered) *when* you load it with `<script src="domain.com/micro-app2.js">`.

Depending on your use case you could trigger the loading on router changes, navigation events, etc.